# How to show popup in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to show `Popup` when I click on `Label` (`LabelShift_MouseDown`). I basically want to edit shift when click on label(one label one shift) but I want when I click label to show popup (edit popup with edit buttons). So can somebody tell me how to do it because this code doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ScheduleItem}" Tag="{Binding .}" Margin="0,10,0,0">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
         <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Start, Converter={StaticResource timeToPositionConverter}}" />
         <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Index}" />
      </Style>
   </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="TimeLineEntry">
         <Label Width="{Binding Duration}" Height="20" Tag="{Binding .}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" MouseDown="LabelShift_MouseDown">
            <Label.Background>
               <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                  <GradientStop Color="#FF3B4DFF" Offset="0.996" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#FF6674F8" Offset="0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFC7CEFF" Offset="0.791" />
               </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Label.Background>
            <Popup>
               <StackPanel>
                  <TextBox Text="Text" />
                  <Button Content="Update" />
                  <Button Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}"/>
               </StackPanel>
            </Popup>
         </Label>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

private void LabelShift_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   Popup p = (sender as Label).Content as Popup;
   p.StaysOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not to define the `Popup` inside the `DataTemplate`. Add it in `Resources` of your window or usercontrol like

```
       <Popup x:Key="myPopup">
           <StackPanel>
              <TextBox Text="Text" />
              <Button Content="Update" />
              <Button Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}"/>
           </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
```

And in the MouseDown handler just do:

```
      Popup popup = Resources["myPopup"] as Popup;
      popup.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;;
      popup.IsOpen = true
```

Comment: I will try that. But is it possible to put `Popup` in `DataTempalte` so every `Label` has his own Popup

Comment: there is a way in which you will need to search the VisualTree of item to find it.. but why would you need it.. single popup can serve the purpose.. if you want the popup to render the data according to its placement target you can set its DataContext to the DataContext of PlacementTarget i.e the sender in teh mouse down

Answer (score 1):

Try `p.IsOpen = true;` instead of `p.StaysOpen = true;`.